# Powershell @{Expression

Tags: powershell

Можно ли в Expression передать вызов get-aduser? Я пытаюсь вытащить из AD электронную почту начальника. ФИО босса выводится правильно, а вот вытащить его емейл не получается.

```
# Вычленяем имя босса из строки
$boss=@{Expression={$_.Manager.Substring(3,$_.Manager.Indexof(",")-3)};Label="BOSS"}

# Выводим список пользователей из города - ФИО, отдел, должность, фио начальника, эл. почта начальника
get-aduser -f {l -eq 'New-York'} -Properties * |where {$_.department -ne $null}| ft CN,department,title,$boss,@{

Label="Boss MAIL";

Expression={get-aduser -f {cn -eq $_.Manager.Substring(3,$_.Manager.Indexof(",")-3)} -Properties * | ft mail}

} -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно. В вашем примере -Filter передается как ScriptBlock вместо String. Также, имеется ошибка в выводе информации по каналу через `ft mail`. `Format-Table` обеспечивает только репрезентативный доступ к данным, т.е. использование отображаемых объектов будет невозможно.

Было:

```
Expression={get-aduser -f {cn -eq $_.Manager.Substring(3,$_.Manager.Indexof(",")-3)} -Properties * | ft mail}
```

Стало:

```
Expression={$Filter = 'cn -eq "{0}"' -f $_.Manager.Substring(3,$_.Manager.Indexof(",")-3); Get-ADUser -Filter $Filter -Properties * | Select -ExpandProperty mail}
```

Я использовал `-F` оператор (.NET [System.String]::Format), определяющий форматирование, где конструкция `{0}` указывает расположение аргументов в строке, которые передаются оператору.

Например,

```
'{0} пятница и я желаю всем {1} настроения.' -f 'Сегодня', 'хорошего'
```

Информацию об этом и других операторах, а также примерах маркеров разметки можно посмотреть в встроенной справке `Get-Help about_Operators`

Comment: Спасибо дружище! Только если не сложно, поясни момент с -eq "{0}" я впервые такую конструкцию вижу. Зачем там ноль в фигурных скобках?

Comment: @Viper, я обновил сообщение с ответом, добавив описание о форматировании.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Счастья и здоровья тебе и твоим близким!